# Selecting a cell at the time of Selecting a row in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Whenever a row is selected in DataGridView, I want a particular cell to be selected instead of while row being selected and also the cursor should start blinking in the cell for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RowEnter` and `CellBeginEdit` events to achieve this.

`RowEnter`

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{     
  //Set the selection mode to cell
  dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;

  //When a row is selected always select the cell in index 1
  dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

`CellBeginEdit`

When a row is selected and user start typing always first cell is being edited, We can set the cell to be edited by setting CurrentCell property.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
   //set the current cell to be edited to cell in index 1
   dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex];
}
```

Comment: Even after incorporating the above both methods, it still ain't working

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. i tested above methods and its working as expected.

Comment: @ShaivyaSharma what is not working ? selecting the cell works ? thats done in CellEnter event.

Comment: The cell is getting selected but the cursor does not start blinking untill I click on the cell twice

Comment: @ShaivyaSharma oh sorry above code will not work like that. it will simply highlight a cell and when user start typing particular cell will be edited.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Change `SelectionMode` of `DataGridView` from `FullRowSelect` to `CellSelect`

Try This:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
```

if you want to edit the `Cell` selected just double click on the `Cell` to enter into EditMode

Answer (score 0):

First , You should reference [Selection Modes in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6w9028%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) !
And this is how to get the selected cell's value

```
yourGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location like this

```
  private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int row = 0;
        int verticalOffset = 0;
        foreach (int h in tableLayoutPanel1.GetRowHeights())
        {
            int column = 0;
            int horizontalOffset = 0;
            foreach(int w in tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths())
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, w, h);
                if(rectangle.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("row {0}, column {1} was clicked", row, column));
                    return;
                }
                horizontalOffset += w;
                column++;
            }
            verticalOffset += h;
            row++;
        }
    }
```